# How can I improve response time of MySql query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, mysql-workbench

I am trying to get the two latest entries from my table where the column idx = 5116 for example.
There are thousands of rows with that index (idx)

Thats my query:
`SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM test4 WHERE idx = 5116 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2) sub ORDER BY id ASC`

The db often takes 30-80s to respond of course depending on the amount of rows with a certain index but is there any way I could speed that whole thing up? Since these response times are decades for a db

My table looks like this:

[image: mysql table screenshot]

Comment: As with any query-optimization question, you should include the `SHOW CREATE TABLE <name>` output for the table(s) referenced in the query, and also the `EXPLAIN <query>` output for the query you are trying to optimize. Help us to help you!

Answer (score 0):

What I feel to suggest is to enable log on slow query in `my.cnf`:

```
slow_query_log = 1
slow-query_log_file = /var/log/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 2
```

Then after have found the incriminate query, we can explore what make it slow using `EXPLAIN`:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM test3 WHERE idx = 5116 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2) sub ORDER BY id ASC;
```

Now we can check some information like rows number, etc... So we can optimize our search add some index with `ALTER_TABLE`:

```
ALTER TABLE test3 ADD INDEX()
```

Cheers.